# Android :: BitmapFactrory Cuts off image

Tags: android, charts, bitmapfactory

We are trying a prototype using Google chart api.

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chf=bg,s,000000&chxs=0,FFFFFF00,9.5&chxt=x&chs=500x300&cht=p3&chco=3072F3|FF9900|80C65A|990066&chd=t:50,5,5,40&chdl=50%C2%B0%20Apples|5%C2%B0%20Oranges|5%C2%B0%20Dates|40%C2%B0%20Strawberries&chdlp=b&chp=0.1
```

[image]

the problem is when we see the chart in the browser it displays the legend. but when we use the BitmapFactory to download the image to an ImageView or even SD card the Legend goes missing (this happens irrespective of where the legend is placed top, bottom, left or right).

here is the code

```
private Bitmap loadChart(URL url){
    Bitmap chart = null;   

    try{            
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        httpConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpConnection.connect();

        InputStream is = httpConnection.getInputStream();           
        chart = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);


    } catch (IOException e) {       
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), chart, "chart.png", "chart.png");

    return chart;
}
```

here is the image which was downloaded by the commented line.

we also noticed that, the dimension of the chart specified in URL (chs=500x300) matches with the image dimension as well.

[image]

Comment: It turned out to be an **Url Encoding** issue. and it loads without any flaws in the webview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using webview which handles url encoding without any additional effort.